# Run a function after each function

Tags: javascript, jquery

For some reason, I can't get a function to run after the each function is complete. This is what I tried and the each function works perfectly but it does not run the other function when it is complete.

```
var delay = 0;
$('h1 span').each(function() {
    var $span = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() { $span.addClass('visible'); }, delay+=1000, function(){
        $('header').addClass('visible');
    });
});
```

Comment: setTimeout() method doesn't accept two 'callbacks'. What behaviour are you expecting here?

Comment: basically, when the function is done adding the class "visible" to each span inside of the h1, I want to run "$('header').addClass('visible');"

Comment: two times setTimeout function maybe? with the same amount of time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your expected behaviour, you can use following logic inside delayed function:

```
var delay = 0;
$('h1 span').each(function () {
    var $span = $(this);
    setTimeout(function () {
        $span.addClass('visible');
        // if $span is last of 'h1 span' matched set
        if ($span.is($('h1 span').last())) {
            $('header').addClass('visible');
        }
    }, delay += 1000);
});
```

### -DEMO-

Comment: Perfecto! Thank you very much. I totally forgot that a setTimeout method does not accept two callbacks.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want to do is this http://jsfiddle.net/gon250/8mdodywe/

setTimeout() function doesn't support two callbacks.

```
$.when($('span').each(function() {
    $(this).addClass('visible');
})).then(function(){
    $('header').addClass('visible');
});
```

Comment: Not sure what your code is supposed to show here? Your code works the same than: http://jsfiddle.net/8mdodywe/1/

Answer (score 0):

I guess that's what you want:

```
var delay = 0;
$('h1 span').each(function() {
    var $span = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() { $span.addClass('visible'); }, delay+=1000);
});
setTimeout(function() { $('header').addClass('visible'); }, delay);
```

Check it out: http://jsfiddle.net/zsm4xegr/

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming, you want two timeouts? From your Code it seems you would like to execute the first timeout after "delay 0". In that case simply execute the first "callback" and set a timout for the second.
If you do indeed want two timeouts (each after 1000ms):

```
$('h1 span').each(function() {
    var $span = $(this);
    setTimeout(
        function() { 
            $span.addClass('visible');
            setTimeout( 
                function() {
                   $('header').addClass('visible');
                },
                1000
             );        
        }, 
        1000        
    );
});
```